# How to change the link color in specific area using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I've taken a look at many questions that I thought were a problem similar to mine but none of them worked for me which is why I'm posting this. I'm still new to programming (just know the basics) so please bear with me:

I own a website [All Gaming Everything](http://www.allgamingeverything.com)

please open any post on the website

The problem I was facing was that all of the `<a>` elements on the website were grey in color so using the custom CSS option in my wordpress theme, I just did

```
a:link { color:white; }
```

Now while this worked like a charm and all of my elements have the same color (white), I want the color of a:link as red on ONLY the body of the article since white prevents the visitor from seeing if there is any link on the post. I tried changing the aspects using inspect element and custom CSS but nothing seems to be working for me. I have access to both custom CSS and custom HTML editors on my wordpress theme so I'd really appreciate any help with this and once again sorry if I talked noobish (I am a noob).

Comment: Not getting exactly what you are trying to say!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector inherited. That means if you have a container with a `<a>` element as child for example

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

do in your css

```
#container a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

or

```
div a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

now all `<a>` in `#container` got red color, if no other declarations from wp stylesheets exists.

Take a look to some great websites like [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) and get the basics of css selectors, childs, parents and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using wordpress and the wygiswys wrap text inside `<p></p>` you can try:

```
p a:link{color:red};
```

and it will change the color of each link inside a paragraphe.

Comment: Notice: Paragraphs always have default padding. Better would be a span or direct styling.

Comment: The Default paragraphe have -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em; (chrome / safari ) 
margin buttom (firefox), depend on the navigator and most of template override the default values

Answer (score 0):

I visited your site and noticed all articles are wrapped in a div with a class "td-post-content". This way, all you have to do is create a CSS rule that targets anchor tags only within those divs.

**Here:**

```
.td-post-content a {
  color: red;
}
```

It workd like a charm. I tested on the post below which has a link within the article body:

[image]

By the way, you don't need to use `a:link` on your CSS statements. Only `a` will do it. ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your help. It worked! :)